# How can I check if a datanode is sending heartbeats to the namenode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have got a strange problem in a Hortonworks hadoop cluster. For one node, the Ambari View is showing that there is no heartbeat being received. However, if I open the log files in `/var/log/hadoop/hdfs`, I don't see any problems in the Datanode daemon's log file. Moreover, if I type `hdfs dfsadmin -report`, the datanode is shown live.

So, my question is how can I properly check if heartbeats are being sent from that datanode? Can I also manually send a heartbeat to the namenode from that datanode? In other words, I would like to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Ambari Agent heartbeats are different from the datanode process

Comment: I see. How does that work. And why am I not receiving heartbeat from one particular node? How can I manually test and debug this?

Comment: `/var/log/ambari-agent/` would be a good place to start

Comment: Ambari Agent is a separate process to supervise and monitor all the other clients and configurations on the machines. Just because that agent isn't responding, doesn't necessarily mean that a node is offline or not running a service